# Check if 443 port is open on remote server

Tags: c#, https

I have an application, that connects to remote server.
When it can't connect, Diagnostics() function run.
One of point in diagnostics is to check 443 port. I check it with next code:

```
public static bool Check443Port(string host)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(host))
                return false;

            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(delegate { return true; });
            HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://" + host);
            myReq.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            HttpWebResponse HttpWResp = (HttpWebResponse)myReq.GetResponse();
            if (HttpWResp.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Logger.WriteLine("Connection to 443 failed: " + HttpWResp.StatusDescription);
                return false;
            }
            HttpWResp.Close();

            Logger.WriteLine("Connection to 443 succeeded");
            return true;
        }
```

Usually it works fine. But one user sent me logs where this function returned FALSE, but 443 port is open (user said). 
Really, from logs i found out, that there is problem not in 443 port, but when i check it, it returns FALSE.

What can be the problem? May be i need another test for 443 port?

P.S. the error is "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."